# What is the total size of cexplorer on Postgres?

Tags: cardano-db-sync, mainnet

I have a relay node fully synced with the tip of the mainnet chain and DB-sync filling the Postgres database. DB-sync is currently syncing on epoch 321 and the database takes 103 GB of disk space. I noticed that as epochs move forward more storage space is required (and syncing is much slower).

I currently have only Postgres filling up a disk volume on Linux of total 187 GB.

My question is, what will be the total size of the cexplorer (for mainnet) database? Do I need more than 187 GB? Currently the chain is on epoch 342.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I noticed that as epochs move forward more storage space is required (and syncing is much slower).

Yes, that is the unfortunate reality.

> I currently have only Postgres filling up a disk volume on Linux of total 187 GB.

It will continue growing. There is an [SQL query](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-db-sync/blob/master/doc/interesting-queries.md#size-of-the-cexplorer-database) that will tell you the size of the database. Last time I ran that on a fully synced database it was 140G.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So it is 140GB in total (currently), that's good! 
I use that query as well to check the size.

Comment: Its is 140G at epoch 336 and we are currently at epoch 342 so its a bit bigger than 140G (and its constantly growing).